# Clickhouse - How can I get distinct values from all values inside an array type column

Tags: clickhouse

On a clickhouse database, I've an array type as column and I want to make an distinct for all elements inside them

Instead of getting this

```
Select distinct errors.message_grouping_fingerprint
FROM views
WHERE  (session_date >= toDate('2022-07-21')) and (session_date < toDate('2022-07-22'))
      and notEmpty(errors.message) = 1
      and project_id = 162
SETTINGS distributed_group_by_no_merge=0


[-8964675922652096680,-8964675922652096680]
[-8964675922652096680]
[-8964675922652096680,-8964675922652096680,-8964675922652096680,-8964675922652096680,-8964675922652096680,-8964675922652096680,-8964675922652096680,-827009490898812590,-8964675922652096680,-8964675922652096680,-8964675922652096680,-8964675922652096680]
[-8964675922652096680,-8964675922652096680,-8964675922652096680]
[-827009490898812590]
[-1660275624223727714,-1660275624223727714]
[1852265010681444046]
[-2552644061611887546]
[-7142229185866234523]
[-7142229185866234523,-7142229185866234523]
```

To get this

```
-8964675922652096680
-827009490898812590
-1660275624223727714
1852265010681444046
-2552644061611887546
-7142229185866234523
```

and finally, to make a count of all them

as 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

groupUniqArrayArray

```sql
select arrayMap( i-> rand()%10, range(rand()%3+1)) arr from numbers(10);
┌─arr─────┐
│ [0]     │
│ [1]     │
│ [7,7,7] │
│ [8,8]   │
│ [9,9,9] │
│ [6,6,6] │
│ [2,2]   │
│ [8,8,8] │
│ [2]     │
│ [8,8,8] │
└─────────┘

SELECT
    groupUniqArrayArray(arr) AS uarr,
    length(uarr)
FROM
(
    SELECT arrayMap(i -> (rand() % 10), range((rand() % 3) + 1)) AS arr
    FROM numbers(10)
)

┌─uarr──────────────┬─length(groupUniqArrayArray(arr))─┐
│ [0,5,9,4,2,8,7,3] │                                8 │
└───────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────┘
```

ARRAY JOIN

```sql
SELECT A
FROM
(
    SELECT arrayMap(i -> (rand() % 10), range((rand() % 3) + 1)) AS arr
    FROM numbers(10)
)
ARRAY JOIN arr AS A
GROUP BY A


┌─A─┐
│ 0 │
│ 1 │
│ 4 │
│ 5 │
│ 6 │
│ 9 │
└───┘
```

Comment: After some fighting, I finally found this 
Select length(arrayDistinct(arrayFlatten(groupArray(errors.message_grouping_fingerprint)))) as Count

Even though, alternative solution provided seems nice too